# getting segmentation error (core dumped) in linked list

Tags: c

I have looked at my code several times but couldn't find the problem. please tell me what I need to replace to get my code working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head;

void insert(int x)
{
    struct node *temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->data = x;

    temp->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        return;
    }

    struct node *temp1 = head;

    while(temp1 != NULL)
    {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    temp1->next = temp;
}

void display()
{ 
struct node *temp = head;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty");
        return;
    }
    else{

        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
       }
    }
}

int main()
{
    head = NULL;

    insert(3);
    insert(5);
    insert(6);
    display();
}
```

Comment: Please only tag one of `C`/`C++`; they are different languages.  I'm guessing this is `C`.

Comment: Do you know "where" you are getting a segmentation fault?

Comment: Use a debugger. At the minimum it will tell you immediately which line of code triggers the seg fault. You can also step through the code and examine the state. Learning to debug effectively is a key dev skill and will be worth the time.

Comment: compiler is not indicating where the actual problem is, its just showing segmentation error

Comment: That's not the compiler's job. Use the right tool - a debugger. On a Linux system a common debugger is [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/).

Comment: If you don't know how to use a debugger, put a printf statement at the start of your insert function to see how many times it gets called, and in which of the invocations the problem happens.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this code:

```
struct node *temp1=head;
while(temp1!=NULL)
{
    temp1=temp1->next;
}
temp1->next=temp;
```

... the while loop won't end until `temp1` is NULL, so after the loop ends, it is guaranteed that `temp1` is a NULL pointer ... and then you dereference that NULL pointer (via `temp1->next`), which causes a crash.  Probably what you want to do instead is `while(temp1->next != NULL) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

```
    while(temp1!=NULL)
    {
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
    temp1->next=temp;
```

The only way out of this loop is for temp1 to be NULL.  Then the next line attempts to used temp1 as a pointer.  This is likely causing your issue.  You need to instead check if the next is NULL and break leaving temp1 as the last in the list not it's next.

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip for linked lists like this, they are a lot easier to modify with double pointers. Example code:

```
void append(struct node **list, int a) {
  // skip to the end of the list:
  while (*list != NULL) {
    list = &(*list)->next;
  }
  *list = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  (*list)->data = a;
  (*list)->next = NULL;
}

void display(struct node *list) {
  while (list) {
    printf("%d\n", list->data);
    list = list->next;
  }
}

void remove(struct node **list, int index) {
  while (*list) {
    if (--index == 0) {
      struct node *temp = *list;
      *list = temp->next;
      free(temp);
      break;
    }
  }
}  

int main() {
  struct list *mylist;
  append(&mylist, 3);
  append(&mylist, 4);
  append(&mylist, 5);
  display(mylist); // prints 3 4 5
  remove(&mylist, 1);
  display(mylist); // prints 3 5
  remove(&mylist, 0);
  remove(&mylist, 0);
  // mylist is NULL again, all memory free'd
}
```

Note that this code needs no special cases for "is the list empty?", which makes it less complex than yours.